# OpenGL glutSwapBuffers does not draw the scene

Tags: linux, opengl

So this is really odd, I'm on ubuntu and when I try running this sample program I can't get the window to show up properly. If I switch it to glFlush and to use GLUT_SINGLE instead of GLUT_DOUBLE then it works perfectly fine. Any reason why this is happening?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

// Initialization routine.
void setup(void)
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
}

// Drawing routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0);
    glColor3f(1,0,1);
    glutSolidCube(1);
    glutSwapBuffers();
    //glFlush();
}

// OpenGL window reshape routine.
void resize(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90.0, (float)w/(float)h, 1.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}

// Main routine.
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    //glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    setup();
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you are setting the clear color and clearing the buffer in the wrong order. This probably will not make ***that big*** a difference since you only use a single clear color in the entire application, but you should be aware that you  need to set the clear color before clearing for it to take effect.

Comment: The other thing is, if your application never calls the resize callback (and chances are good that it will not, since you setup the callback ***after*** you init your window's size and position), then your matrices will not be setup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't tempt fate, reset your matrices every time through your display callback:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void drawScene()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    gluPerspective(60, w / h, 1.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0);

    glColor3f(1,0,1);
    glutSolidCube(1);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Also, setting the `eye` and `center` points in [`gluLookAt()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) to the same position is [Bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero) (see the calculation of the `F` and `f` vectors).